# How to pass a function to WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, c, .net, webassembly, wasmtime

I have a simple function compiled using the [WASI SDK](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wasi-sdk), intended to receive a function pointer to pass to another C library that is supposed to call it at a later time (and with an arbitrary signature):

```c
__attribute__((export_name("add_func")))
void add_func(void* func) {
    // pass func to some other API expecting void*
}
```

The WASM module is loaded and executed through [`wasmtime-dotnet`](https://github.com/bytecodealliance/wasmtime-dotnet), where I want to dynamically create an arbitrary number of functions and pass them to `add_func`, in this manner:

```cs
Instance inst = ...;
var add_func = inst.GetAction<Function>("add_func");
add_func(Function.FromCallback(_store, (caller, arguments, results) => {
   ...
});
```

However, `inst.GetAction<Function>` returns `null`, and the only way to retrieve and call this function seems to be with an `int` parameter, like `GetAction<int>`.

How do I pass a function created in this way to WASM? I could not find any way to either change the signature of the function to allow funcref arguments, or to obtain the index of the created function (I reckon function pointers are indexes in WASM anyway).